# C#, Winform, Sql Server and Config file

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, app-config

I have a C# winform app named xyz.exe. It operates using xyz.config  file. The config file is a plain text file and in it I put my settings I need to run my app , such as how many times it has to iterate,  what files to read, what are the default values etc etc. It works just fine.  All is working OK.  Today I started to work on some enhancement request, I need to make a connection to a sql server database and retrieve some information. Very straight forward.

If I run debug (F5) all is working OK. But if I run it from command prompt by typing xyz.exe it throws exception **"The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory' threw an exception."** and it points to the connection section. if I rename xyz.config to something else , the exception went away. if I create a blank App.config (this will generate xyz.exe.config), the exception went away.

What is going on? Can anybody explain this to me and what are the possible solutions, options, best solution? is is possible to make the app to not looking for xyz.config and xyz.exe.config w/o throwing exception. It was ok before I introduce connection to db.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
                                "user id=xx;" +
                                "password=xx;" +
                                "server=xx;" +
                                "database=xx; " +
                                "connection timeout=xx");

try
{
   connection.Open();
}

catch (Exception e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}

try
{
   SqlDataReader myReader = null;
   SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from xx",
                                                             connection);
   myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
   while (myReader.Read())
   {
      Console.WriteLine(myReader["xx"].ToString());
      Console.WriteLine(myReader["xx"].ToString());
   }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Your config file should be called xyz.exe.config. Is it named like that in the folder you run from in command line?

Comment: my config file is xyz.config. if I created an empty config file (add , new item, App.config), I would have xyz.exe.config

Comment: Config files should be named <exename>.exe.config

Comment: it seems if I do not have sql connection the config file name is not enforced (hence I can use xyz.config). is this enforcement can be overriden? or turn off?

Comment: Why can't you have the default name? Is it some kind of restriction you have?

Comment: this is a working app. and it is using xyz.config. the app read the config using streamreader. now I need to implement sql connection and I have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Config files should be named `<exename>.exe.config`, e.g. if your exe name is `xyz.exe`, its config file name should be `xyz.exe.config`.

If you want to use non-standard names, you have to read config files manually.

Comment: I did read the config files manually. seems you misunderstand the problem

Comment: I tried a simple app which reads from SQL Server, I didn't need any config file at all. Something makes your code use `SqlConnectionFactory` which shouldn't be necessary.